# How to determine if a date was a public holiday in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I am writing a code in python and at one stage I need to determine if some given past dates were public holidays or days off in a certain locality such as New York, London, Tokyo, Sydney. I am only concerned with past dates (going back to 2002) and days off that actually happened regardless of whether they were officially planned or not. My dates are represented as a list of datetime objects and I use pytz to indicate localities. How can this be done in python?

Comment: From the help, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow…" A much better way to find a Python library is to [search on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=holiday&submit=search).

Comment: A quick search didn't find anything, but I think that without much effort you could use an online database like [this](http://www.qppstudio.net/publicholidays.htm) or [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/), then with a library like mechanize, you can parse these databases into your python file. You could use some math to go back for each year you need.

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 the databases you link to list only holidays for 2013. I don't think using math to go back to previous years is a good idea.

Comment: By "use some math," I mean use a library to shift the date back a year. Even though there might be a couple errors, (which you can manually correct), what holidays are there that are only specifically in one year? I agree that it's not the best idea, but there isn't really any better alternative...

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 shifting the dates back a year will introduce too many errors. It is unreliable.

Comment: Actually, timeanddate.com (second link in cloudcoder2000 comment) has public holidays going back to 2000.

Comment: @abarnert I've edited my question to be on-topic.

Comment: @cloudcoder2000: Try shifting Easter back one year, or Passover, or even Presidents Day …

Comment: @AndreySokolov: Did you look at any of the results from the search I linked, or try searching on your own, or look at the sites cloudcoder2000 linked, or try searching on your own? It looks like the `holiday` library, or scraping `timeanddate.com`, should work.

Comment: @abarnert holiday library is only for Brazil, Poland, and United Kingdom as far as I can see. Any suggestions on how to automate scraping timeanddate.com?

Comment: @AndreySokolov: Nobody is going to teach you the basics of web scraping in comments on a StackOverflow question. And there are plenty of good tutorials online that are better than what any of us would have written. Meanwhile, the fact that you didn't even look at things people found in searches until being asked three times, and still haven't even tried your own search, doesn't exactly motivate people to try to answer you. Whether fairly or not, most people will assume that you're just looking for someone to write your code for you, and unless you pay people, they're not going to do that.

Comment: @abarnet I'm not saying that all holidays will work, but most will, and since there are only 10 years needed, it is easy to just manually set the dates for these holidays.

Answer (score 3):

You can download a .ics file with official hollidays from [Mozilla - Calendar Holiday Files](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/holidays.html) and then use [pyICSParser](http://pythonhosted.org/pyICSParser/) to build a set where you store the results. I do not know of any resource, there will give you hollidays for specific locations.

Then just use the set to check if dates are hollidays.

Best of luck.

Comment: It would be really helpful for future visitors if you could include code in your answer.  It'd also turn your answer up to [11](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEEQtwIwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DN3L4EZwmRrA&ei=hmuyUsDNJKbMsAT-1YGACg&usg=AFQjCNHcnWXcXPlPzBkkweGly2jKeVAjqQ&sig2=H2GOht7z9thOjKyqnWMtGw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.cWc).